# Python: ¿Como acelerar script de python? Asincrono

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, asincronismo

Verán tengo este script

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pymysql
import ipaddress
red_ipv4 = ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.1.0/24')

for ip in red_ipv4:
    try:
        conexion = pymysql.connect(host=str(ip),
                             user='gviera',
                             password='hola',
                             db='calificaciones')
        try:
            with conexion.cursor() as cursor:
                for consulta in range(1,11):
                    consulta = "INSERT INTO pbd2019 VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"
                    cursor.execute(consulta, ("216411051","Frank Miller", 100))
                    conexion.commit()
        finally:
            conexion.close()
    except (pymysql.err.OperationalError, pymysql.err.InternalError) as e:
        print("Ocurrió un error al conectar: ", e)
```

Si funciona pero quisiera acelerarlo ya que la función de este script es insertar varios registros en distintos host de mysql en un segmento de red, me habían comentado anteriormente que con el map asincrono se podia agilizar pero no le entendí bien como hacerlo, podrían darme un ejemplo de como quedaría

De antemano gracias.

Comment: En vez de hacer 10 consultas de insert, puedes generar una consulta concatenando VALUES. `VALUES (...), (...), ...`

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @frank-miller? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que ejecutas el mismo codigo SQL en varios host distintos sin necesidad que estos interactúen, no existe necesidad de hacer estas peticiones de manera secuencial, entonces como tu mencionas, puedes aprovechar las características concurrentes / multi-hilo de Python para optimizar este codigo.

Dado que posees una lista de `hostnames`, y quieres ejecutar una funcion para cada elemento, puedes utilizar un map en paralelo, en particular recomiendo la librería incluida desde `python 3.2+` [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) .

El codigo quedaría así:

```
import pymysql
import ipaddress
import concurrent.futures

red_ipv4 = ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.1.0/24')
number_of_workers = 4


def do_query(ip):
    try:
        conexion = pymysql.connect(host=str(ip),
                             user='gviera',
                             password='hola',
                             db='calificaciones')
        try:
            with conexion.cursor() as cursor:
                for consulta in range(1,11):
                    consulta = "INSERT INTO pbd2019 VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"
                    cursor.execute(consulta, ("216411051","Frank Miller", 100))
                    conexion.commit()
        finally:
            conexion.close()
    except (pymysql.err.OperationalError, pymysql.err.InternalError) as e:
        print("Ocurrió un error al conectar: ", e)
        return -1
    return 0

# gatillar evaluacion de map en paralelo con number_of_workers threads maximo
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=number_of_workers) as executor:
    # map es asincrono, por lo que no bloquea la siguiente instruccion
    result = executor.map(do_query, red_ipv4)

# esperamos hasta que se termine el map evaluando el iterador que retorna el map
result = list(result)
```